# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ where $x_{n+1}=2 x_n^2-1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_{n+1}=2 x_n^2-1$ for all $n\geq 0$. Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ in the following two cases:

1. $x_0=1/2$.
2. $x_0=2$.

Comment: How can there be two separate $x_0$? Are those two different questions?

Comment: Excuse me, the text was unclear. I just edited it. Practically asked to calculate two limits, the first with $x_0=1/2$, the second with $x_0=2$.

Comment: For the first case, here's a hint, try calculating the first couple of elements. Also do you just need to calculate the limit or do you also need to formally prove it via delta-epsilon proofs?

Comment: I'm just need to calculate the limit. I don't have much experience with the limits of recursive sequences.

Comment: @Mark Just write out the first few terms of $x_n$ in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)$: You can prove: $x_n = -\dfrac{1}{2}, \forall n \geq 1 \Rightarrow x_n \to -\dfrac{1}{2}$.

$2)$: You can prove: $x_n > n, \forall n \geq 1 \to x_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

As you've probably already noticed, the limit of this sequence depends on the starting position.  However, If we consider the limit of $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$, we see that, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n}$$  How could it be anything different?  Thus, if we let $$\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n}=L$$  and use our recurrence formula, we obtain $L=2L^2-1$.  Solving this equation yields $L=-1/2$ or $L=1$, but which one is it?  Like I said, it depends on your starting position.  Try calculating the first few terms of each starting position, and see what happens.  Perhaps there are some starting positions that don't yield a limit?  In addition to what i've already asked you, i find it interesting to ask the following question:  What starting value will yield the limit $L=1$?  (It's not one that you're given.)